# Created event doesn't show up in Behavior->Events->Overview tab

Tags: google-workspace, google-analytics

I have an Email Tracking event set up. I can clearly see the Event Category in Real Time->Events tab.

> **Real Time->Events ta**
>   [image]

But nothing shows up in the Behavior->Events->Overview tab.

> **Behavior->Events->Overview tab**
>   [image]

I have set the data range correctly. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Show your event code, pls.